# Travel options from nuremberg to Seattle

Tags: budget, atlantic-ocean

I want to have a vacation in Seattle and i am looking for a cheap way to get there.

I am aware of [flight search engines](https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=NUE;t=SEA) - and the cheapest i found was something around 1500$ for one week during Christmas.

It is the other side of the globe so i assume this is quite a good price however i am not aware of other travel options there might be. Something like an atlantic cruise maybe or even more options.

What options are there and where can i find more information about them?

Comment: I very much doubt you will find anything significantly cheaper than a commercial airline flight, for which a search engine is a good way to find one.  Sometimes prices fluctuate, so you could get a better deal by waiting a little while and checking again (or not). Cruises are usually luxury affairs that cost much more.

Comment: Also consider other airports.  I found a flight from Frankfurt to Seattle for $922 round-trip on Icelandair.  To get from Nuremberg to the Frankfurt airport is about 2.5 hours and 31 euros each way by ICE train.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commercial airliner will be the cheapest. Boat would be extremely expensive (since it's 6 nights or so across the Atlantic) plus another east coast to west coast flight.

www.hipmunk.com is a good search sight. Over Christmas flights will be expensive since it's busy season. Starting to book now is a good idea. Cheapest that I found was about $1200 (Dec 23 to Dec 30) either through Frankfurt or Paris.

You can increase the chances of a good price by being flexible on dates and airports. In Germany you can consider also Frankfurt or Munich which are both Lufthansa hubs. However, sometimes the smaller airports with an extra leg are actually cheaper (makes no sense, but it's so frequent that it has it's own name called "hidden city ticketing".

So you just have to spend some time running various options and pick the cheapest that's inside your comfort zone for dates, travel time, layovers, etc.